# How to add third party dependencies to typescript reference projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have three typescript projects which all reference a single 'core' module.

```
project-a
project-b
project-c
core
```

I would like to add some utilities that rely on a third party dependency. This can be an express middleware, winston logger, etc. For example, a default winston logger. So inside `core`, i may have

**core/src/logger/index.ts**

```js
import winston from 'winston'
export default winston.createLogger()
```

This file is referenced by **project-a** and **project-b** but not **project-c**. How do I set up my **core** project in a way that accommodates this? I was thinking the following steps:

- Move this file into a brand new typescript project
- Reference in `project-a` and `project-b`
- Add `winston` to dependencies and install as usual `npm i -S winston`
- Run tsc -b on `project-a`

Would this be the ideal way of doing it? I would be adding third party references to the shared code, but no way of enforcing a dependency to be installed similar to `peerDependencies` in node.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could accomplish this, but one of the easiest might be [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Examples).

When you initialize your core code, you could optionally pass in a type the implements some "`Logger`" interface (which you could define), then in project-a and -b you could pass in a class, etc, that implements the winston logger. In project-c, you simply don't pass in any logger, and so core won't use it.

In this case, your core project would have no direct reference to winston. Only projects -a and -b would have it, and project-c would be free from unnecessary dependencies.

However, depending on your setup, [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) may eliminate the extra dependencies in project-c, so you might be fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Winston was more of an example, I have updated my question a little just to clarify. Another example would be some express middleware i'd like to share across applications. So its less a DI thing and more the process of writing third party library extensions that I can share.

Comment: If you are compiling your projects, then winston is likely packaged up in your core project, in which case your projects a, b and c don't need to declare this dependency on their own. Maybe I'm still not understanding something though.

Comment: Sounds like you got it. `shared` wants to, for another example, have some `express` middleware all projects use. To write this, i'll need to reference `express`. As you say, the projects will contain the reference to express, but there's no way to 'force' any projects referencing `shared` to install `express`, and I'd have to install `express` in the shared project, despite never using it when actually building so I thought I was doing something incorrectly. Sorry if that was a bit of a spaghetti explanation.

Comment: Ah... got you. I guess it depends on the package manager you are using, but NPM usually handles this pretty well. If packages couldn't install their dependencies, then most packages wouldn't run correctly ([which has happened before](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/))

Comment: The 2 folders are only linked via references at the minute and are used via typescript aliases to give a nice absolute path. They're not currently linked through node/npm so there's nothing to advise what is necessary. I thought about `npm link` but then I've joined them twice via ts and npm and it seems to get confused as to where this code is. As you say, simply installing the package in shared, build merging the code and relying on the 'host' to have it installed works, but is.. not ideal if you get me.

Comment: Yeah... you are kind of stuck, then. If you just want to import the modules directly, then you'll need to add the npm dependencies to your project-a, -b and -c. If you don't want to pollute your packages with the extra dependencies, then you'll need to treat your core project as an NPM package and then let NPM handle installation of packages, etc. There may be a way around this, but I don't know of one.

Comment: @plusheen - actually, workspaces might be what you need. But I've not used them yet so I can't offer much more guidance. https://blog.bitsrc.io/npm-7-this-is-what-i-call-an-update-de17a34ab787

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, guess I'm overthinking it. Just this weird mishmash of typescript references and also wanting to kinda link with npm. Workspaces sounds pretty close to what I need, but our runtime is currently node 14. Starting to wish I just went with nx or something haha. Appreciate the help, think i'll push for npm 7 for this feature.